# Keeping track of a variable from one controller to another

Tags: laravel, variables, eloquent, many-to-many

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

I am currently learning Laravel and I seem to not be able to wrap my head around a problem.

I am trying to create a quotation and invoice solution for a company that has dealers selling their product.

So what I have is a salesperson that has created a client using a form. The input is stored in a client table.

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('system_id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('contact')->nullable();
        $table->string('number')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->nullable();
```

Part of the form the salesperson selects the "system" that they want to quote the client on, this is the `system_id` above.

The `user_id` above refers merely to the salesperson that created the client.

Here is my products `migration`

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('group');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->double('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The client is stored successfully. Afterwards I use an if statement to determine which `route` to follow to configure the system.

```
if ($data['system_id'] == 1){
      return redirect(route('system.824'))->with('success', 'Customer details have been saved.');
  }elseif($data['system_id'] == 2){
      return redirect(route('system.32'))->with('success', 'Customer details have been saved.');
  }elseif ($data['system_id']==3){
      return redirect(route('system.500'))->with('success', 'Customer details have        been saved.');
  }
```

The `routes` above goes to a certain function inside my `SystemsController`, here I retrieve the required "groups" as referred to above in my `products` migration.

These groups are used to configure the `systems`.

After the systems are configured the data is sent back to the SystemsController for me to perform the required validation and further logic for the configuration on the input received.

After the system is configured it is then sent to the `SystemsController` where I need to perform some logic based on the form input.

My issue is the accessing the `client_id` in the SystemsController so I can store the input received into the pivot table I created.

The `client_id` `hasMany` `products`
The `products` `hasMany` `clients`

I need to use the pivot table to keep track of what was quoted on in the configuration for that client. The pivot table will contain the client_id and the product_id with a a final column to save the quantity.

What am I missing here?

Thank you again.

Comment: you can send any amount of data inside the `with`. Either use multiple with or use an array. I will add an answer if you are still confused.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If I understand you correctly I would pass the data inside the with statement and allow for it inside my routes to the destination where it is needed. There I would be able to use get, access the variable from my route?

Comment: Yes, just like you access the 'success' message.

Comment: To pass it to a route, the route itself should have a parameter defined. and then you can pass that values. Although you can find in the documentation, I will add an answer with some examples.

Comment: @user3532758 Thank you so much for the advice. What I did that worked for me was to add the data inside the `with`, I then passed the data into a hidden input and passed the data with the information to the controller. If you do however post an example I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help, and best of luck on your Laravel learning journey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, you could send more data inside the `with`, either as an array or concatenating more `with`s.

```
return redirect(route('system.32'))->with('success', 'Customer details have been saved.')->with('user_id', $userId);
```

OR

```
return redirect(route('system.32'))->with(['success' => 'success message', 'user_id' => $userId]);
```

Referring to your comment, if you want to pass data inside the route action, you would need your route set up like so:

```
Route::get('path/to/your/route/system_input/{infoId}', 'SystemController@getInput')->name('system.input')
```

The method in SystemController should accept the parameter.

```
public function getInput($infoId) {
```

Then, in your redirect route:

```
return redirect(route('system.input', ['infoId' => $info->id]) );
```

Now you will have access to the infoId in your `getInput` method via `$infoId`.